# Conditional probability of two sequential samples

Tags: integration, conditional-probability, bayesian

Suppose we model a distribution over $27$ alphabet symbols with the random variable  $\mathbf{X} $, a vector which takes a multinomial distribution, parameterized by $\mathbf{\theta}=(\theta_1, ..., \theta_{27})$ where $\sum_{i=1}^{27} \theta_i = 1$.   Let $\mathbf{X}\textbf{[i]} = (X_1 \textbf{[i]}, X_2\textbf{[i]}, ... X_{27}\textbf{[i]})$ denote  the $i$th sample observed.

We use a Dirichlet prior over $\theta$, with parameter $\mathbf{\alpha}= (\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_{27})$,  where each $\alpha_i = 10$

$$
\xi (\theta) = \frac{\Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^{27} \alpha_i)}{\Pi_{i=1}^{27}\Gamma(\alpha_i)} \Pi_{i=1}^{27}\theta_i^{\alpha_i-1}
$$

After observing $2000$ samples, of which $100$ are  "a" and $87$ are  "P",  I have that the posterior is a Dirichlet distribution over $\mathbf{\theta}$ with parameters $\small \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{\alpha} + \mathbf{X} = (b_1 = \alpha_1 + 100, b_2 = \alpha_2 + X_2, ..., b_{15} = \alpha_{15} + 87, ... b_{27} = \alpha_{27} + X_{27})$.

That is, 
$ P(\mathbf{\theta}|\mathbf{b}\textbf{[1]},\mathbf{b}\textbf{[2]}, ... \mathbf{b}\textbf{[2000]}) $

$$=\int_{\theta} \frac{\Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^{27} \alpha_i + 2000 )}{\Gamma(b_1)\Gamma(b_{15})\Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^{27} \alpha_i + 2000- (b_1 + b_{15}))} \theta_{1}^{b_1-1}\theta_{15}^{b_{15}-1}...\theta_{27}^{b_{27-1}}  \mathrm d\theta  $$

$$=\int_{\theta} \frac{\Gamma(2270 )}{\Gamma(110)\Gamma(97)\Gamma(2063)} \theta_{1}^{110-1}\theta_{15}^{97-1}...\theta_{27}^{b_{27}-1}  \mathrm d\theta  $$

My question is how to find the probability that the next two samples ($i=2001, 2002$)  are the symbols "a" and  "p" , given  $\mathbf{X}\textbf{[1]}...\mathbf{X}\textbf{[2000]}$.

i.e., how to find  $P(\mathbf{X_1}\textbf{[2002]} = a, \mathbf{X_{15}}\textbf{ [2001]} = p  \mid  \mathbf{X}\textbf{[1]}...\mathbf{X}\textbf{[2000]})$.

Assuming $\mathbf{X}\textbf{[i]}$ is conditionally independent of $  \mathbf{X}\textbf{[i+1]}$ given $\theta$, is the following headed toward the solution?

$$P(\mathbf{X_1}\textbf{[2002]} = a, \mathbf{X_{15}}\textbf{ [2001]} = p  \mid  \mathbf{X}\textbf{[1]}...\mathbf{X}\textbf{[2000]})
$$
$$=  \int_{\theta} P(\mathbf{X_1}\textbf{[2002]} = a, \mathbf{X_{15}}\textbf{ [2001]} = p \mid \theta)P(\mathbf{\theta}|\mathbf{X}\textbf{[1]},\mathbf{X}\textbf{[2]}, ... \mathbf{X}\textbf{[2000]})  \mathrm d\theta  $$ 
$$=  \int_{\theta} P(\mathbf{X_1}\textbf{[2002]} = a \mid \theta)P( \mathbf{X_{15}}\textbf{ [2001]} = p \mid \theta)P(\mathbf{\theta}|\mathbf{X}\textbf{[1]},\mathbf{X}\textbf{[2]}, ... \mathbf{X}\textbf{[2000]})  \mathrm d\theta  $$

$$=  \int_{\theta} \theta_{1} \theta_{15} P(\mathbf{\theta}|\mathbf{X}\textbf{[1]},\mathbf{X}\textbf{[2]}, ... \mathbf{X}\textbf{[2000]})  \mathrm d\theta  $$

$$=\int_{\theta} \theta_{1} \theta_{15} \frac{\Gamma(2270 )}{\Gamma(110)\Gamma(97)\Gamma(2063)} \theta_{1}^{110}\theta_{15}^{97}...\theta_{27}^{b_{27}}  \mathrm d\theta  $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%20%28%20Gamma%282270%29%20/%20%28%20Gamma%2897%29Gamma%28110%29Gamma%282063%29%20%29%29%2ax%2ay%20%2ax%5E%2897-1%29%20%2a%20%28y%5E%28110-1%29%20%29%20%2a%20%28%20%28%201-%28x%2by%29%20%29%5E%282063-1%29%20%29%20dy%20dx,%20for%20x%20=%200..1,%20y%20=%200..%281-x%29) is how to solve it. $\mathbf{X}_{2001}$ may be conditionally independent of $\mathbf{X}_{2002}$ given $\theta$, but  $\mathbf{X}_{2001},\mathbf{X}_{2002}$ are not conditionally independent given $\mathbf{X}$.